# Ideal solution for the following case scenario in database

Tags: join, oracle11g, sql-server-2008-r2, indexing, rdbms

There are 50 exams to be written by around millions of students online, One person may or may not write more than one exam. A person can also write a single exam more than one time ( retries ) ..

So which of the below solution is better for this case, `I am okay with a better solution than these two as well`

Option 1. Store each exam in a single table :

Subject 1

```
+----------------+---------+
|   student id   |  Marks  |
+----------------+---------+
| 1              | 85      |
| 2              | 32      |
| 2              | 60      |
+----------------+---------+
```

Subject 2

```
+----------------+---------+
|   student id   |  Marks  |
+----------------+---------+
| 1              | 85      |
| 2              | 32      |
| 2              | 60      |
+----------------+---------+
```

Like above with each table will have the student id only if that particular person has taken that exam , and have multiple occurrences of the student id if he has taken it more than once.

Option 2 :

```
+----------------+---------+---------+
|   student id   | Subject |  Marks  |
+----------------+---------+---------+
| 1              | Subj1   | 85      |
| 2              | Subj1   | 32      |
| 2              | Subj1   | 60      |
| 1              | Subj2   | 80      |
| 3              | Subj2   | 90      |
+----------------+---------+---------+
```

with all the values in a single table.

Which is better in terms of performance and storage perspective.

My various que

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best here is following:

1. Table `STUDENT` with information about students
2. Table `EXAM` with information about exams
3. Table `EXAM_TRY` with reference to `STUDENT` and `EXAM` tables, and fields `DATE_OF_EXAM` and `RESULT_OF_EXAM`
4. 2 indexes on foreign keys in table `EXAM_TRY`
5. Depending on situation - index on date field (for example, you would need it for planning work for examiners)

Comment: EXAM_TRY is for each exam or all the exams together ?

Comment: So you mean more like option 2 , with Student id referred from student table and subject name referred from subject table and their corresponding marks. Did I get you correctly ?

Comment: As I can see - yes. But in such questions better to write DDL queries for tables, they couldn't be understood wrong.